# I can't get the title to change on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, graphics

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.title("Calculator")
```

**`Above is the code that I am using. It just doesn't seem to work for some reason.`
**

This seems to be the correct way as far as Google is concerned LOL. I need some expertise!

Comment: The screen is updated only during show().

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem after adding missing `win.mainloop()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was unable to reproduce the error. 
First lets check that Tkinter is properly installed in your system if everything is working correctly a tkinter window show open.

```
python -m tkinter
```

Second try the code bellow
main.py

```py
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.title("Calculator")

win.mainloop()
```

Further reading: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html

Comment: Thank you for your help! I changed my file to "main.py" and that seemed to do the trick! Silly error on my end.